# Custom string as query output

Tags: influxdb, influxql

Is it possible to get a custom string as a query output of SELECT query in influxQL?

```
> select time, uuid1, uuid2, id from mydb."autogen".data limit 1;
name: measurement1
time                 uuid1       uuid2                                id
----                ------------ -----------                          ---------------
1555321822616000000 ###    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001       45337
```

I would like to get "hai" instead of ### in my query output.

I tried this one:

```
> select time, uuid1 as "hai", uuid2, id from mydb."autogen".data limit 1;
name: measurement1
time                 uuid1       uuid2                                id
----                ------------ -----------                          ---------------
1555321822616000000              00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 45337
```

My expected result is as follows:

```
time                 uuid1       uuid2                                id
----                ------------ -----------                          ---------------
1555321822616000000     "hai"    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 45337
```